# Assign group to consecutive 1s in a Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, events, time-series

I have a column in pandas having values 0 and 1. I want to assign group number where there are more than 9 consecutive 1.

Example:
Say my column values are: `[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

I want a new column or change the same column to: `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]`

I got upto a point where I can replace all the consecutive 1s (count greater than 9) by another number say 2. Here is the code:

```
def f(col, threshold=9):
    mask = col.groupby((col != col.shift()).cumsum()).transform('count').gt(threshold)
    mask &= col.eq(1)
    #print (mask)
    col.update(col.loc[mask].replace(1,2))
    return col
```

Comment: Why people make such long examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find consecutive groups of 1s and determine the size of those groups. Use `where` to mask any groups of 0s, or groups of 1s that are too small, then `ngroup` will allow you to label them properly. `NaN` rows get labeled -1 and you want the counting to start at 1, so adding `1` fixes both of these simultaneously.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
               1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
               1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])

u = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum().where(s.eq(1))  # Label consecutive groups of 1s, NaN 0s
u = u.groupby(u).transform('size').gt(9)     # True only if 1s and size > 9.

# Any smaller groups or 0s get NaN'd by `where` which are labeled -1 by `ngroup`
result = u.groupby(u.ne(u.shift()).cumsum().where(u)).ngroup()+1

print(results.tolist())
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach:

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
               1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
               1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])

# groupby and filter those with >=9 ones
u = s.groupby(s.ne(1).cumsum()).transform('sum').ge(9) & s

# count the groups of True:
(~u.shift(fill_value=False) & u).cumsum().mul(u)
```

Output:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
```